Proving that $\limsup X_n/n=\infty$
I have trouble with an exercise, and would appreciate some help!
Let $X_1,X_2,...$ ne iid r.v. with PDF $f_{X_n}(t)=\frac{1}{t^2}\mathbb 1_{t\geq1}$
A) calculate $\mathbb E(X_n)$ and $\mathbb P(X_n>s)$
well, $\mathbb E(X)=\int_1^\infty\frac{t}{t^2}=\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{t}=\infty$
$\mathbb P(X>s)=1-\int_1^s\frac{1}{t^2}=\frac{1}{s}$
b)show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup\frac{X_n}{n}=\infty$
$\mathbb P(\frac{X_n}{n}>s)=\mathbb P(X_n>ns)=\frac{1}{ns}$
so the event $\{X_n>ns\}=:A_n$
Since those $X_n$ are iid we can use Borel-Cantelli lemma 2 because
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb P(A_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{1}{ns}=\infty$ for fixed $s\geq1$.
Then $\mathbb{P} (\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup\{X_n>ns\})=1$
So we get, that for infinitely many $n\in \mathbb N $ is $X_n>ns$ and it must tend to infinity since the  $X_n's$ are iid.
Can i deduce the claim from the above that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup\frac{X_n}{n}$ must be $\infty$
Thanks for your help in advance!

Essentially yes, or at least with probability $1$ and so almost surely $\limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{X_n}{n}=\infty$.  Personally I would prefer it if you gave $s$ a value, such as $1$.

Let
$$
A_n=\left\{\frac{X_n}n\ge \ln n\right\}=\{X_n\ge n\ln n\}. 
$$
Then $\mathbb{P}(A_n)=\frac1{n\ln n}$. As you said, by the Borel-Cantelli lemma, if $B=\{A_n$ occurs infinitely often$\}$ then $\mathbb{P}(B)=1$. On the other hand, on $B$, $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{X_n}n=+\infty$. Hence
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{X_n}n=+\infty\right)=1.
$$
